# Font and rear card animation with CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I am trying to develop my webpage with some animation effects, and I have three cards with front and back flip animation effect. Now I am looking for front and back animation effect, which I have described in below image clearly.

Image before front and back animation (Initially).

[image: Image Before animation]

Image after click on card-2,

[image: Image after animation]

**Example:**

```js
var accHD = document.getElementsByClassName('card');
var showNotificationBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('showsettingsbutton');

for (i = 0; i < accHD.length; i++) {
    showNotificationBtn[i].addEventListener(
        'click', function toggleItem() {
                     var itemClass = this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.className;
                     for (i = 0; i < showNotificationBtn.length; i++) {
                         showNotificationBtn[i].parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.className = 'card';
                         showNotificationBtn[i].parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.className = 'flipper';
                     }
                     this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.className = 'cardlarge';
                     this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.className = 'flipperRotaion';
                 }
    );
}
```

```css
.card {
    padding: 30px;
    background: #fff;
    /*box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);*/
    transition: 0.3s;
    width: 10%;
    z-index: 1;
}

.container {
    padding: 2px 16px;
}

.cardlarge {
    padding: 30px;
    background: #fff;
    transition: 0.3s;
    width: 10%;
    -moz-transition: all 2s; -webkit-transition : all 2s; -o-transition :
    all 2s; transition : all 2s;
    z-index: 2;
    -webkit-transition: all 2s;
    -o-transition: all 2s;
    transition: all 2s;
}
/*Card Design ends here*/
/*Flip Design starts here*/
.flip-container {
    perspective: 1000px;
}
/* flip the pane when hovered 
.flip-container:hover .flipper, .flip-container.hover .flipper {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
*/
.flipperRotaion {
    transition: 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: relative;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
/* flip speed goes here */
.flipper {
    transition: 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: relative;
}
/* hide back of pane during swap */
.front, .back {
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
/* front pane, placed above back */
.front {
    z-index: 2;
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

/* back, initially hidden pane */
.back {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
/*Flip Design ends here*/
/*Show Notification button design starts here*/
.showsettingsbutton {
    border: 0;
    background: #0087cc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 0 #006599;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    font: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    transition: all .1s linear;
}

.showsettingsbutton:active {
    box-shadow: 0 2px 0 #006599;
    transform: translateY(3px);
}
```

```html
<div class="cardlist" align="center">
    <div class="card" style="float:left;">
        <div class="flip-container">
            <div class="flipper">
                <div class="front">
                    <!-- front content -->
                    <img src="Assert/Settings-icon.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
                    <div class="container">
                        <h4><b>Alert Setting</b></h4>
                        <p>Setting descriptions</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="showsettings">
                        <button class="showsettingsbutton">Show Settings</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="back">
                <!-- back content -->
                    <img src="Assert/Settings-icon-2.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
                    <div class="container">
                        <h4><b>Alert Setting</b></h4>
                        <p>Setting descriptions</p>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="Notification" value="Email">Email
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card" style="float:left;">
        <div class="flip-container">
            <div class="flipper">
                <div class="front">
                    <!-- front content -->
                    <img src="Assert/Settings-icon.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
                    <div class="container">
                        <h4><b>Alert Setting</b></h4>
                        <p>Setting descriptions</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="showsettings">
                        <button class="showsettingsbutton">Show Settings</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="back">
                <!-- back content -->
                    Back        
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card" style="float:left;">
        <div class="flip-container">
            <div class="flipper">
                <div class="front">
                    <!-- front content -->
                    <img src="Assert/Settings-icon.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
                    <div class="container">
                        <h4><b>Alert Setting</b></h4>
                        <p>Setting descriptions</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="showsettings">
                        <button class="showsettingsbutton">Show Settings</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="back">
                <!-- back content -->
                    <img src="Assert/Settings-icon-2.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
                    <div class="container">
                        <h4><b>Alert Setting</b></h4>
                        <p>Setting descriptions</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>      
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what are you asking? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Javascript Error: `accHD is not defined`.

Comment: accHD is defined, now i updated the code above

Comment: when i click on any card, clicked card comes front with increased width size and others cards are go behind to that card (i.e., clicked card), like cyclic rotation.